# Keeping IIS Express Alive

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, iis-express

My Question is that I Develop a ASP.net Web Service in C#.net 3.5 , and when I run it from the Visual studio the IIS Express run and all work fine.

but when I open a new project, or Closing The VS , the IIS Express Stops !!

can any one help me how to keep it alive

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if your site is actually hosted in IIS or its just running from VS. If you site is hosted in IIS you can set the timeout period in the App Pool that your site is using. Which is normally set to go to sleep after 20minutes. But you can set is as you like. If you don't want to set that in IIS you can set that is "machine.config" file but its not recommended.

Have a look at this post if this meets your requirement. 
    http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771956(v=ws.10).aspx